# Calculate the Probability of winning (wins/ (wins + losses)) with 10,000 simulations in the game of craps.. this is part of an assignment

Tags: java, simulation, probability

Calculate the Probability of winning (`wins/ (wins + losses)`) using 10,000 simulations in the game of craps. Here is the method for the game of craps:

```
public class CrapsGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int dice1 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
            int dice2 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
            int roll = dice1 + dice2;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("You rolled "+roll+". ");
            if(roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12){
                    System.out.println("You Lose !");
            }else if(roll == 7 || roll == 11){
                    System.out.println("You Win !");
            }else{
                    System.out.println("Point is "+roll+"\n");
                    dice1 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
                    dice2 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
                    int roll2 = dice1 + dice2;
                    System.out.print("You rolled "+roll2+". ");
                    while(roll2 != 7){
                            if(roll == roll2){
                                    System.out.println("You Win !");
                                    break;
                            }else{
                                    System.out.println("Point is "+roll+"\n");
                            }
                            dice1 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
                            dice2 = (int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1;
                            roll2 = dice1 + dice2;
                            System.out.print("You rolled "+roll2+". ");
                    }
                    if(roll2 == 7){
                            System.out.println("You Lose !");
                    }                       
            }
    }
}
```

I don't think this should be difficult, I just need code to run 10,000 simulations and then also calculating the probability. Thank you :)

Would it be possible to have someone insert a working version of this

Putting a while or for loop outside of the logic and creating 2 counters (timesWinning, timesLosing). Incrementing each according, inside the existing code. After the loop runs 10.000 times, do the math as needed: wins/ (wins + losses)

thank you this is part of an assignment

Comment: Put a `while` or `for` loop outside your logic and create 2 counters (timesWinning, timesLosing). Increment each according, inside your existing code. After the loop runs 10.000 times, do the math as needed: `wins/ (wins + losses)`.

Comment: sorry i'm kind of new to Java, would you mind helping me with the actual code? it doesn't seem overly difficult, and thanks for the help so far if you're busy can't help I can probably find help again

Comment: Is this an assignment from school?

Comment: yes, but help from the web is fine teach says so

Comment: Okay, from the web, could be understood as reading tutorials. SO is not against answering assignments, but it's recommended that you write this in your question description. Can you do that? If so, I try to give you the way to fix it.

Comment: okays done thank you tom

Comment: sorry that i didn't understand the etiquette here

Comment: what I asked you was just to say in the question that this is part of an assignment. I'll write down the answer to help you, but please try to understand what's in the code.

Comment: i'm not bad at understanding the code, sometimes actually writing it out can be difficult.. edited it to how you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has already all the logic needed. To repeat it as many times you want, there are different ways. They are known as `loops`. If you search on Google you will find `for`, `while`, `do/while` and some others (you have a `while` already inside the code).

For your question, the basic would be to repeat it 10,000 times the same things.

```
public class CrapsGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create some variables to control the times it won and times it lost
        int timesWon = 0;
        int timesLost = 0;


        // Here we're saying it's gonna repeat 10000 times, incrementing 1 by 1
        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
            // Here you will insert all the existing logic from your program

            // In the existing code, increment the variables declared according

            if(roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12){
                System.out.println("You Lose !");
                timesLost++;
            }else if(roll == 7 || roll == 11){
                System.out.println("You Win !");
                timesWon++;
            }else{
                // Where you find it won, insert `timesWon++;`
                // Where you find it lost, insert `timesLost++;`
            }
        }
        // Here it exits the for loop (after 10000 times)
        // Here's where you can calculate

        System.out.println("Probability of winning: " + (timesWon/(timesWon + timesLost)));
    }
}
```

This should be sufficient to get the desired result.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

And you should modify his code to this at the end:

```
 System.out.println("Probability of winning: " +  ((double)timesWon/(timesWon + timesLost)));
```

I got this as a result from my own:

You played:  10000.0, won:  5078, probability of winning : 0.5078

You played:  1.0E8, won:  50707214, probability of winning : 0.50707214

Comment: do you think you could give me your code? I'm running into a bit of trouble trying to get this up and running..

Comment: What's the issue?  The above is what you need to do.  Are you having trouble with the brackets?  Highlight everything a press ctr i in your eclipse to get everything to line up, that makes it much easier.

Comment: i am having trouble with the brackets :( & installing eclipse on this rental computer!!! arrRrgG